# Custom video-js width and height on Dynamically Loaded Content

Tags: javascript, zurb-foundation, video.js

I'm [dynamically loading video-js](http://docs.videojs.com/docs/guides/setup.html#alternative-setup-for-dynamically-loaded-html) inside a [foundation reveal](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/v/5.5.3/components/reveal.html), and I have to trigger the width and height each time it loads. The odd thing is, once I've loaded one video on the page, it won't change it again no matter what, it only sticks to the one size.

This is my code

```
    $(document).on('opened.fndtn', '[data-reveal]', function () {
        if($('.sd-video').length) {
            console.log('SD Detected');
            videojs($('.sd-video')[0], {"width": 640,"height": 480}, function() {});
        }
        if($('.hd-video').length) {
            console.log('HD Detected');
            videojs($('.hd-video')[0], {"width": 1287,"height": 720}, function() {});
        }
    });
    $(document).on('closed.fndtn', '[data-reveal]', function () {
        $('#'+$(this).attr('id')).html('');
    });
```

and no matter what I try, once it's loaded HD, the SD will not resize, and vice-versa. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to change by using CSS values. It does not matter whether the player is loaded or not. You can change the dimensions even when the video is playing.

For example, you can check this example https://codepen.io/caglar62/pen/BebKMX.

You can change the dimensions of the video player with one button click like this

```
<div class="container">
    <video id="my-video" class="video-js" controls preload="auto" width="870" height="364" ></video>
    <input type="button" value="Click me" onclick="changeSize()">
</div>    

<script>
   function changeSize(){
      document.getElementById("my-video").style.width = "200px";
   }
</script>
```

This is just a simple example but you can write more complicated algorithms that suit your purpose in the same approach.